# is there anyway i can add stripslashes to all variables

Tags: php

adding stripslashes to all variables while retrieving from the database is driving me crazy. is there i can do this automagically.

Comment: Then why did you add that unneeded slashes to the database?

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic sign of double-escaping.  You should correct your code so it doesn't escape prematurely.  To prevent SQL injection, simply use prepared statements (e.g. [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) or [MySQLi_STMT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php)).  You do not have to escape manually, and if you use these correctly, your database will not contain slash-escaped data.

You will have to do a one-time batch run through your database to fix the current data.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the database retrieval logic into a single access point (method or class) and strip slashes there. Then all the rest of the code can use this method/class.

Answer (score 0):

convert your data into array

lets for now

$data is array

```
array_map('stripslashes', $data);
```

this will automatically add sriptslashes to every data elemnt in $data array

Answer (score 0):

Disable magic_quotes **everywhere**